# md5() works with literal, but not with column data

Tags: postgresql, md5

While testing out [PostgreSQL's `md5()` function](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html) I noticed very bizarre behavior:

**Works as expected**

```
SELECT md5('abc')
--"900150983cd24fb0d6963f7d28e17f72"
```

**But using the md5() function in a query:**

```
SELECT request_id, md5(request_id)
FROM Request
ORDER BY request_id
```

results in this error:

```
ERROR:  function md5(integer) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT request_id, md5(request_id)
                           ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

********** Error **********

ERROR: function md5(integer) does not exist
SQL state: 42883
Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
Character: 20
```

How can the function *not* exist if it worked in the first query? **What am I doing wrong; what is the correct way to use `md5()` in a SELECT query?**

Comment: That doesn't seem bizarre at all. In the first query, you passed text, while in the second one you're trying to pass integers.

Comment: @us2012: yup, that's the difference.

Comment: In general it doesn't make much sense to take the md5 of an integer, so I'd be interested in why you're trying to do this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The function expects text as parameter. Cast it:

```
SELECT request_id, md5(request_id::text)
FROM Request
ORDER BY request_id
```

A function named md5 accepting an integer parameter does not exist but you can create it:

```
create function md5(integer)
returns text as $$

select md5($1::text);

$$ language sql immutable;
```

Then there will be 3 signatures for md5:

```
=> \df md5
                          List of functions
   Schema   | Name | Result data type | Argument data types |  Type  
------------+------+------------------+---------------------+--------
 pg_catalog | md5  | text             | bytea               | normal
 pg_catalog | md5  | text             | text                | normal
 public     | md5  | text             | integer             | normal
```

As pointed in the comments to this answer the md5 hash of the integer's text representation may not be what you want. To have the hash of the binary the md5 signature accepting a `bytea` parameter should be used:

```
select md5(('\x' || right('0000000' || to_hex(200), 8))::bytea);
               md5                
----------------------------------
 b7b436d004c1cc0501bee9e296d2eaa4
```

And replace the previously created function:

```
create or replace function md5(integer)
returns text as $$

select md5(('\x' || right('0000000' || to_hex($1), 8))::bytea);

$$ language sql immutable;
```

Comment: True story. I figured it out right after I posted the question. Thanks Clodoaldo.

Comment: Note that casting the integer to text means you're taking the md5 of the *textual representation of the integer*. This may not be what you intend when communicating with other systems. If you really want to take the md5 of the integer's binary representation you'll need to use a procedural language like pl/perl, pl/python, etc to take the md5 of the appropriate binary representation (signed 32-bit little endian, for example).

Comment: @Craig Good point. But it looks like a procedural language is not necessary. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @ClodoaldoNeto Clever approach, though you are indeed missing something. `to_hex` doesn't let you control the representation; it looks like it's always a two's complement little endian 32-bit integer; see `SELECT to_hex(-1);`. That's fine if that's the format you need, but it might not be. Anyway, this is clearly total pedantry for the OP's actual needs, I raised the original point before the OP had explained what they were trying to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

In general it doesn't make much sense to take the md5 of an integer. It seems likely that you trying to obscure a sequence so it appears semi-random in order. If so, there's a much better way:

Use the [`pseudo_encrypt` function listed on the PostgreSQL wiki](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Pseudo_encrypt). It's way saner than trying to take the md5 of an integer then (presumably) truncate it.

The above does *not* provide strong cryptographic randomness, but neither does your approach. If you need your request IDs to be genuinely unpredictable for security reasons rather than just non-obvious at a casual glance you should be using a strong cryptographic random numbers generator and be prepared to cope with duplicates using time windows, etc.

Comment: I'm just trying to generate a non-obvious, non-repeating, value which can be used to look-up a record. So my bright (?) idea is to do some sort of encryption on the tble's PL. It's security-by-anonymity made necessary because casual users (ticket requesters) will not have logins. Anyway, I landed on using  `REPLACE(request_id::text,'1234567890','abcdefghij')` to do this "encryption".

Comment: PS--your "Awooga! Awooga!" still cracks me up.

Comment: @JeromyFrench What can I say, I love Holly and like making jokes only us oldies will get ;-) . Like a lecturer I had at uni that'd make extremely funny Monkey references in her talks; four or five of us in the theatre would crack up laughing and the everyone else would look at us like we'd gone quite mad.

Comment: @JeromyFrench The word you're looking for is probably "obfuscation". It sounds like you do want an unpredictable and sparse namespace, in which case I'd certainly consider using random numbers and adding a qualifier like '123121/2' for de-duplication. You could alternately generate a new random number when there's a collision or use a *large* random value to render collision proabilities near zero.

Comment: @JeromyFrench For example, `SELECT to_hex((random()*10^15)::bigint) || to_hex((random()*10^15)::bigint)` would do a pretty decent job.

Answer (score 1):

The error is a little misleading; the `md5()` function exists, just not for working on *integers*. Use an embedded `CAST()` function to convert the integer field into text, and it will work:

```
SELECT request_id, md5(CAST(request_id AS TEXT))
FROM Request
ORDER BY request_id

--1;"c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b"
--2;"c81e728d9d4c2f636f067f89cc14862c"
--etc
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm just trying to generate a non-obvious, non-repeating, value which
>   can be used to look-up a record.

What you need is a bijective hash. I use the `CRC` CPU function in a custom C function. For CPUs that don't have the function, one can use a lookup table.

This approach is guaranteed to give you a unique "random looking" number for every unique 32-bit input.

If you know how to generate C functions (not trivial), it will be a simple task to look up how to use CRC.